# Parsing using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing

I ma new to java.
I have a string s:

```
s="<name>header</name><content>Good Morning</content>"
```

How to get value of content and name using Jsoup?
What JSoup returns when content is empty?null?

Comment: Have you tried something..

Comment: Please post your attempt

Comment: this attempt at a question makes no sense

Comment: http://www.hascode.com/2012/12/content-detection-metadata-and-content-extraction-with-apache-tika/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsoup:

```
        Connection con2=Jsoup.connect(url);
        Document doc = con2.get();
        //or use Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element e=doc.head().select("meta[name=header]").first();
        String url=e.attr("content");
```

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

**For your edit I do agree with the answer that @Hein give you.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this RegEx for example: `name=(.*) content=(.*) \/>`. The name will be in the first group and the content in the second.

I would recommend double quotes around the strings though. In that case you can use this regex: `name=\"(.*)\" content=\"(.*)\"`

**Edit after the OPs edit:**

If you have complete control of the data yourself you should consider saving the name and content in seperate columns in your database, or look into serialization maybe.

Comment: +1 for the simple and good solution to the malformed markup, -1 for suggesting the same approach for a well-formed one (if you have valid markup, use a proper parsing library, [not regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/520779))

Comment: @mgibsonbr You're probably right, but you **could** use regex too, then you wouldn't have to depend on another library for such a simple case. There are multiple solutions, this is just one.

Comment: Sure, I agree sometimes a quick and dirty solution might be the most sensible thing to do, especially if it's an one-off task.